# "être tête en l'air": Why use "être", not "avoir"?

Tags: expressions

> Tu **es** bien **tête en l'air** ce matin !

I use this phrase to express the idea of "*avoir la tête dans les nuages*", but I have always wondered why it is coupled with "*être*" rather than "*avoir*". To see "être" used like this... it sure is bizarre. Can someone explain this grammatical construction?

On another note: I have heard French speakers say "*tu **as** la tête en l'air*" a couple of times before, but I'm not sure it is a legitimate variant.

Answer (score 3):

Les deux constructions sont légitimes.

- Dans "*tu **es** tête en l'air*" tête en l'air fait fonction de locution adjectivale. Ici attribut.
- Dans "*tu **as la** tête en l'air*" tête en l'air est une locution nominale. Ici complément.

Les deux sont grammaticalement correctes. La première est préférée pour laisser entendre un comportement récurrent, un état d'être, la seconde pour parler d'ici et maintenant.